# Lenovo G700: no sound in headphones

Tags: lenovo, alsa, hda-intel

I have Lenovo G700 and have no sound in headphones :(

Lenovo G700, IDT 92HD95, Kubuntu 14.04.

Alsa updated from "ALSA daily build snapshots", kernel updated to 4.0rc6, alsamixer checked. Internal speakers are working fine. No same problem on Windows 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: recent update "from ALSA daily build snapshots" brings fix for this problem. thanks2all

Answer (score -1):

Use command gstreamer-properties in terminal, in the window it opens you can select the interfaces for audio/video input and output. It helped me with a similar problem. To use that command, if you haven't, you have to install gnome-media package.

Comment: @mikewhatever There is no link in this answer... Why did you flag it as link-only? But rok: Your answer is pretty short anyway. Could you please improve it by adding some explanations? That would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed, there isn't.

Comment: i'm using KDE, so instead gstreamer-properties i have "System Settings" > "Audio and Video Settings". Exactly is already checked.

Comment: Improved my answer, see if it can help you